# Find unbiased estimator of $\theta$ when $f(x;\theta )=\frac{2x}{\theta }e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{\theta }}$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value, parameter-estimation

Let $f(x;\theta )=\frac{2x}{\theta }e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{\theta }}$ be a probability density function of sample $(X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n})$ where $x\geq 0$. Find unbiased estimator for $\theta$.

**Here is my solution :** $E\left [ \bar{X} \right ] = E\left [ X \right ]=\frac{1}{\theta }\int_{0}^{\infty }2x^{2}e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{\theta }}dx=\frac{1}{\theta }\int_{0}^{\infty }xe^{\frac{-x^{2}}{\theta }}2xdx$

Let $$  t=\frac{x^{2}}{\theta } (t=\frac{x^{2}}{\theta }\Rightarrow \theta t=x^{2}\Rightarrow x=\sqrt{\theta t},x\geq 0) , dt=\frac{2x}{\theta }d\theta \Rightarrow \theta dt=2xdx$$

$=\frac{1}{\theta }\int_{0}^{\infty }(\theta )^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{-t}\theta dt=\frac{\theta ^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\theta }\int_{0}^{\infty }t^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{-t}dt=\sqrt{\theta }.\Gamma (\frac{3}{2})=\sqrt{\theta }.\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$

$\Rightarrow E\left ( \bar{X} \right )=\sqrt{\theta }.\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\Rightarrow E(\frac{4\bar{(X)}^{2}}{\pi})=\theta $

Hence unbiased estimator for $\theta$ is $\hat{\theta }=\frac{4\bar{(X)}^{2}}{\pi}$

Is my solution right? I am not sure the calculation. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: $E[X^2] ≠ E[X]^2$, in general

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You correctly calculated that $E(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\theta \pi}$. But as noted in the comments this does not allow you to compute $E(x^2)$. If you actually calculate that ([wolfram alpha)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20x%5E2%20*%202*x%2Ft*exp%28-x%5E2%2Ft%29%20for%20x%3D0%20to%20infinity), you will find
$$ E(x^2) = \int x^2\ f(x;\theta)\ dx=\theta.$$
which means that $x^2$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$.

Comment: I've found $E(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\theta\pi }$ not $E(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\theta x }$

Comment: oups, sry. yes you are right of course, that was just a typo when copying from wolfram alpha^^. just edited the answer.

Comment: thanks for  correcting my mistake

Answer (score 1):

@softglance: The estimator you found is a nice estimator and it is exactly the Method of Moment estimator for $\theta$

Unfortunately it is not very easy to calculate its expectation.

A clever approach is the one showed by @Simon (+1) but it consider only one observation.

To calculate its expectation no integrals are needed, just observe that your density is a known one, a [Rayleigh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution) with

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\sqrt{\theta}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

$$\mathbb{V}[X]=\frac{4-\pi}{4}\theta$$

thus

$$\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]=\mathbb{V}[X]+\mathbb{E}^2[X]=\theta$$

If you want to get an unbiased estimator for $\theta$ using all you $n-$ sized random sample simply use

$$T=\frac{\sum_iX_i^2}{n}$$

that is obviously unbiased.

Another way is to remember that $Y=\sum_iX_i^2\sim Gamma\left(n;\frac{1}{\theta}\right)$

with expectation $E(Y)=n\theta$ and thus if you choose $T=\frac{Y}{n}$ you get an unbiased estimator

Comment: I am really confused right now. We can have so many approaches right? So $x^{2}$ can be unbiased estimator for $\theta $, right?

Comment: @softglance: yes of course! better to indicate, for example $T=X_1^2$ as an unbiased estimator because the estimator must be a function of the random sample. In this approach you take the first observation of your $n$ size sample and its square value is the estimation of your parameter. It is unbiased but not so good, as you do not use the remaining $(n-1)$ observations.  I gave you a further step finding an unbiased estimator based on the full random sample

Comment: Thanks for the information, can you check my another unbiased estimator question in my asked question section ? Someone solved for beta distribution but I don't get it. Could you give me an hint or something?

Comment: @softglance :If the question is this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4165050/finding-unbiased-estimator-for-theta, the answer is perfect (+1) and to get it I suggest you to follow the posted solution step by step.

First calculate the distribution of 

$$Y=\frac{X-\theta}{b-\theta}$$

and realize that

$$f_Y(y)=2y$$

with mean $E(Y)=2/3$ Then using linearity of the expectation find the rest of the solution.

The proposed standardization is quite easy to find because the given family of densities belongs to a Location -Scale family

Comment: Okay thank you :)